# Read larger number of text files using task (TPL concept)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am trying to read around 300 text files line by line and the size of each file is 50 to 70 MB. I am using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` for reading and writing the files. Currently i am using `foreach` loop for the iterations and it is taking 8 to 10 min to read the entire folder of files.
I am new to TPL concept and don't know how to implement it to read the folder of hundreds of text files. Can anyone help me by giving a code snippet that shows how to use task to read files more faster.

Comment: This will be IO-bound rather than compute-bound and using multiple threads is unlikely to speed it up - in fact, using multiple threads to access a hard disk is likely to slow things down as the poor disk heads go flying backwards and forwards...

Answer (score 1):

This is already pretty fast if you're using a HDD.

I'm supposing that your bottleneck is the IO. If it's the CPU however (doing some big operations with the file), and you have an SSD, or any other medium with negligible access time, I suggest you look at `Parallel.ForEach` as well.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) => 
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(currentFile, FileMode.Open ))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
                string s;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //do your stuff here
                }
        }
    });
```

DO NOT use the Parallel method when doing IO on a magnetic mechanical HDD.

Comment: `FileStream` is *already* buffered by default. Its constructor also has [an overload which lets you specify a non-default size](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20d7x6t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Similarly, `StreamReader` also has a constructor to select a buffer size.

Comment: @MatthewWatson oh, it's merged. Silly me. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/15/114329.aspx I'll edit the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You may create multiple tasks and use `WaitAll` method to wait until all finishes.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var file in someFileList)
{
   tasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {               
             ProcessFile(file);
        });
   );
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.toArray());
```

Comment: -1 for using `Task.Factory.StartNew` (instead of `Task.Run`) and `Task.WaitAll` (instead of `await Task.WhenAll`. It's 2016, time to stop using blocking calls when there are easier-to-use alternatives!

Comment: Also, there's normally really no point in spawning a multitude of threads when we're doing something IO bound. Use an IO api that exposes naturally asynchronous methods, or don't do them asynchronously at all.